# setting Breeze js naming conventions to "camelCase" is resulting in an error when getting metadata

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, naming-conventions, breeze

I have a Web App built using breeze js to communicate with a breeze api controller on top of entity framework.

I want to have the properties names and nav properties by in camelCase. on the server they are PascalCase.

Following the instructions [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/naming-convention) I added this to my code:

```
 breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
```

As a result I am now getting an error when breeze is trying to get the metadata

```
 Error: Metadata import failed for Breeze/ZenAPI/Metadata; Unable to process
 returned metadata:NamingConvention for this server property name does not roundtrip properly:houseId-->HouseId
```

Things I know:

1. All the properties are PascalCased on the server.
2. There is no non default formatter set on the server.
3. When I look at the server response it is in Pascal.
4. If I take out this setting, everything works fine and the naming is Pascal.
5. The setting is set, meaning that when I check

   breeze.NamingConvention.defaultInstance.name;

I get "camelCase";

What might be the reason for the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NamingConvention.camelCase is intended for use in converting server property names that are PascalCased into CamelCased names on the client.  According to the error message, you are trying to do the reverse, i.e. in your case 'houseId' is a server property name.

When metadata is being processed breeze attempts to verify that every property name can be roundtripped by passing it thru the *NamingConvention.clientPropertyNameToServer* method and then thru the *NamingConvention.serverPropertyNameToClient* method or the reverse depending on whether a client or a server name is provided within the metadata.  The message you got indicates that

```
ServerName   ClientName   ServerName   
----------   ----------   ---------  
'houseId' -> 'houseId' -> 'HouseId'   ( 'houseId' != 'HouseId');
```

Note that if 'HouseId' was the server name then this works just fine.

```
ServerName   ClientName   ServerName   
----------   ----------   ---------  
'HouseId' -> 'houseId' -> 'HouseId'   ( 'HouseId' == 'HouseId');
```

If it turns out that you really do want 'houseId' as both the server name and the client name, then you will need to write your own NamingConvention ( which is actually pretty easy). See http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/NamingConvention.html

Comment: but the server name is "HoueseId". that is the name on the backend code, and in the json. so i think the second option you show should be happening, but isn't.

Comment: This error message only occurs if breeze thinks that the server name is 'houseId'.  How are you generating your metadata? There are two properties on each DataProperty in the metadata, a 'name' and a 'nameOnServer', you can set either one but my guess is that you are setting 'name' ( the client side name) to 'HouseId', instead of setting 'nameOnServer'.

Comment: auto generated pocos by Entity Framework. Where the names of the props and the entities are all PascalCase. also, if that is really the case. why is the JSON showing PascalCase?

Comment: And when looking inside the breeze metadata store nameOnServer :  Id,SentenceId . and so on.

Comment: found out that a single prop (HouseId) has a different name for some reason. all the rest is camelCase. i'm marking your answer as right as it explains the subject in a clear manner and might help someone else understand that that the problem is in their code.

Comment: any idea about how I can exclude an entity from the meta data?

Comment: I'm not sure you want to actually exclude it, but you can with the [NotMapped] annotation.  But this will completely eliminate the property from breeze ever knowing about it.  A better solution would be to write your own NamingConvention that is like the "camelCase" convention but has a specific exception for 'houseId'. NamingConvention methods are only run once per property and the results then cached, so perf isn't much of an issue.

Comment: I did create one, mostly because properties that are all uppercase should not be changed. GDP stays GDP. sadly I hit on more problem, breeze can't handle the letter "P" when it appears at the beginning of a string to compere with a property of type enum. turns it into edm.time"ProprotyValueStartingWithP".

Answer (score 0):

I found that with Code First generation of the model with Entity Framework Powertools on EF6+ did not allow for the selection of database objects, consequently the table "sysdiagrams" came across all in lowercase instead of the Pascal Case notation I normally use for db objects.  Once I removed this table from the model and context classes, then this error with breeze went away.  All good.  I also tested with  breeze.NamingConvention.none.setAsDefault() and used Pascal case in my javascript and that worked OK too, but not preferred.